# Error running rspec test in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Hi I have created a test case in spec/myprocess as follows

```
before :each do
  @my_base = MyBase.new
end

describe "new_my_base" do
  it "should not take any arguments and retuens a MyBase object" do
    @my_base.should be_an_instance_of MyBase
  end
end

describe "#my_path" do
  it "returns the correct mybase file path" do
     $path.should eql App::Application.config.my_encode_type.to_s
  end
end
```

and when I tun rspec spec/lib/mybasetest.rb it throws me the following error.

```
kalanamith@kalanamith:~/Documents/projects/leena$ rspec spec/lib/mybasetest.rb 


*** Mocha deprecation warning: Change `require 'mocha'` to `require 'mocha/setup'`.

/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in     `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.

*** Mocha deprecation warning: `require 'mocha/standalone'` has been deprecated. Please    use `require 'mocha/api' instead.

/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in      `require': cannot load such file -- mocha/object (LoadError)

/home/kalanamith/Documents/projects/fakturabank/spec/lib/mybasetest.rb:4:in `<top     (required)>': undefined method `before' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

This is my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'jquery-rails' , '3.0.0'

gem 'pg'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rails-dev-tweaks', '~> 0.6.1'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  gem 'simplecov-rcov', :require => false
  gem 'pry'
  gem "guard-rspec"
end

group :test do
  gem 'mocha'
end

group :test do
  gem "webmock"
end

gem 'debugger' # This gem works with ruby 1.9.3 it wraps these other things
 gem 'savon', "~> 1.2.0"
 gem 'airbrake'
 gem 'aasm'
 gem 'paranoia'
 gem 'acts_as_tree'
 gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'translate-rails3'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
 gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'libxml-ruby'
gem 'libxslt-ruby'
gem 'ruby-xslt'
gem 'exception_notification', :require => 'exception_notifier'
gem "uuidtools", "~> 2.1.3"
gem "ruby-filemagic"
 gem "rmagick", :require => false
 gem "rubyzip"
 gem "spreadsheet"
 gem "multi_json"
  gem "multi_xml"
 gem "httparty"

#FormBuilder backwards compatibility
gem "dynamic_form"
 gem "prototype-rails"

 gem "formtastic"

 gem "net-ssh"
 gem "net-scp"
```

Um quite new to rails and this is my first experience with rspec framework . I will be grateful if anyone can assist me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you call `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of file ? Because `spec_helper` will include necessary libraries, including rspec.

Comment: well yes I did include

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be a "**describe**" that wraps before :each do

```
describe "Bla bla" do
  before :each do
    @my_base = MyBase.new
  end

  etc...


end
```

Anyway, the file name should be suffixed with _spec.rb

Answer (score 1):

The `before` block should be inside the `describe` method

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RSpec the end of the file must be suffixed with `_spec.rb`

Example: `my_base_spec.rb`

To Run: `bundle exec rspec spec/my_base_spec.rb` or simply `bundle exec rspec`